# What to use: boolean variable instead or a null value for true/false recognition

Tags: java

The question is quite simple.

```
Object obj;

obj = new Object();

if(obj!=null) {
    // this means my object is *set*
}
```

The other

```
Object obj;
Boolean objSet = false;

obj = new Object();
objSet = true;

if(objSet) {
    // this means my object is *set*
}
```

Which one is more *correct*. I hear databases and some methods act will null in different ways.

Comment: *"I hear databases and some methods act will null in different ways."* -  what you are you referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Correct" is not the word of choice. If it compiles and does what it should, it is correct.

As a matter of usefulness, I would better use the more direct check. Adding a boolean variable to avoid performing a `== null` check means extra (minimal overhead), more lines, difficults readability and can introduce errors.

Add the boolean variable if the condition is complicated enough that you need to explicit it (vg., if you have to check that all/any in a set of conditions are met).

And BTW, since you are using `Boolean` and not `boolean`, you introduce the possibility that `objSet` is null itself if you do not code it well.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is more *correct*:

- From the perspective of behavioural semantics, they do the same thing ... assuming that they are correctly implemented.
- From a performance perspective, the difference is *probably* negligible in the context of the entire application.
- From a space usage perspective, the difference is *probably* negligible ... unless `obj` and `objSet` are fields and you have a many, many instances of the relevant class.
- From a robustness perspective (e.g. avoiding unexpected NPEs) there is no qualitative difference.  You can get an NPE in either case if you forget to do the test.  (I guess if you changed the example to include something that changes `obj`, then the version with a separate flag is more complicated, and hence harder to get right.   But if you encapsulate the logic in a setter method then you only need to get it right once ...)

So really, it boils down to which version of the code is more readable.  And that is subjective ... so "more correct" doesn't come into it.  Most experienced programmers would probably recognize the idiom and prefer the first version.

Comment: Thank you for double clarifying!